# automatic way to make sure that the formulas and text does not go beyond the margin

Tags: margins

Is there any automatic way to make sure that the formulas and text does not go beyond the margin in latex. Not \linebreak in appropriate places. My text/math formulas are going beyond the margin in the right side

Thanks for the help

Comment: After you decided the final margins you have to set up formulas manually to check for overfull. You have to format the equations to avoid that. It is not automatic. But if you use the LaTeX commands with caution it will be almost right.

Comment: Can you show an example?

Comment: You could put all your equations in a \resizebox or \adjustbox[width=\textwidth,clip=right] and force the suckers to fit.